# suppose p is fermat prime and p>3, show that $\left(\frac{7}{p}\right) = -1$

Tags: number-theory

suppose p is fermat prime, show that $\left(\frac{7}{p}\right) = -1$

We wish to solve $\left(\frac{7}{p}\right) = -1$ for $p$. By quadratic reciprocity and the fact that $7 \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ we know $\left(\frac{7}{p}\right) = - \left(\frac{p}{7}\right)$.

By a simple calculation, we see that $\left(\frac{7}{p}\right) = -1$ if $p \equiv 1,2,4 \pmod{7}$.

I know that fermat primes are equal to $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ either.

How can i use this information to conclude that $\left(\frac{7}{p}\right) = -1$?

Comment: No, $\left(\frac{7}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{p}{7}\right)$, because $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, assuming $p>3$ (if $p=3$, the claim is false).

Comment: This is only true if the fermat prime is larger than $3$.

Comment: o yes of course we can get 3 as well, didn't notic that thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fermat primes are of the form $p=2^{2^{k}}+1$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z_{\ge 0}$. If $k=0$, your claim is wrong; but it's true if $k\ge 1$. I'll assume $k\ge 1$.

We know $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, so by Quadratic Reciprocity $\left(\frac{7}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{p}{7}\right)$.

We know $2^{2^k}+1\equiv \{5,3\}\pmod{7}$, none of which is a quadratic residue, so $\left(\frac{p}{7}\right)=-1$.

Comment: how do you see that $2^{2^{k}} + 1 \equiv \{3,5\} \pmod{7}$?

Comment: @KeesTil, $2^{2^{k+1}}=(2^{2^k})^2$, so the pertinent powers of $2$ mod $7$ toggle back and forth between $2$ and $4$.  I.e., $2^2=4$ and $4^2=16\equiv2$ mod $7$.